# Youtube Data-api code stopped working - Update video Metadata Functionality

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Developing Java web based application. Where i am trying to update my youtube video title, description or tags. Earlier code was working perfectly fine. Suddenly it has stopped working when I give execute request. Mostly I have used the code sample given in java. Below is my code sample from main java file. I am sentting the values in constructor.  I have made bold the line where it is giving error. Is anyone else as well facing this challenge suddenly. And what is the resolution.

Error --- 
There was a service error: 400 : The request metadata is invalid.
14:01:20.567 [main] ERROR com.analytics.youtube.UpdateYoutubeContent - There was a service error: 400 : The request metadata is invalid.

```
this.setConnection(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"),"updatevideo");
            logger.info("After Setting Connection");
            YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = this.ytConn.videos().list("snippet").setId(this.sId);
            VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();
            List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();
            if (videoList.isEmpty()) {
                //System.out.println("Can't find a video with ID: " + videoId);
                throw (new Exception("Can't find a video with ID: "+this.sId));
            }
            Video video = videoList.get(0);
            VideoSnippet snippet = video.getSnippet();
            if(this.sTitle != ""){
                snippet.setTitle(this.sTitle);
                System.out.println("Title");
            }
            if(this.sDescription != ""){
                snippet.setDescription(this.sDescription);   
                System.out.println("Description");
            }
            if(this.sTags.get(0) != ""){
                snippet.setTags(this.sTags);
                System.out.println("Tags");
            }
            System.out.println(this.sTitle);
            System.out.println(this.sDescription);
            System.out.println(this.sTags.get(0));
//            snippet.

            YouTube.Videos.Update updateVideosRequest = this.ytConn.videos().update("snippet", video);
            **Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();**


            logger.info("Before Catch");
        }catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            logger.error("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ logger.info("Inside Catch");
            logger.error("Error Message--"+ ex.getMessage() + "  Cause--" + ex.getCause());
            throw ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [possible errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#general-errors) you encountered, since I cannot see the bold line in the code.

> **commentThreads**
>
> The following tables identify error messages that the API returns in
>   response to calls related to commentThreads resources. These methods
>   could also return errors listed in the [Common errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#common) section.
>
> - commentThreads.insert
> - commentThreads.update
>
> **comments**
>
> The following tables identify error messages that the API returns in
>   response to calls related to comments resources. These methods could
>   also return errors listed in the [Common errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#common) section.
>
> - comments.insert
> - comments.update
>
> **videos**
>
> The following tables identify error messages that the API returns in
>   response to calls related to videos resources. These methods could
>   also return errors listed in the [Common errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#common) section.
>
> - videos.insert - **The request metadata is invalid**. This error occurs if the request updates the [**snippet**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) part of a **video**
>     resource but does not set a value for both the **snippet**.**title**
>     and **snippet.categoryId** properties.
> - videos.update - **The request metadata is invalid**. This error occurs if the request updates the [**snippet**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) part of a **video**
>     resource but does not set a value for both the **snippet.title** and
>     **snippet.categoryId** properties.

Comment: Getting error at execute. **Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();**

Comment: Getting error at execute. **Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();**  2.3 weeks back same code was working. Now its stopped. I am updating Either Title or description or tags or all 3 or 2. Code will handle based on my front end. Why should I update Category Id? It should take category Id same as earlier which was there before requesting update. Even Google sample code does not say anything on updating category id is mandatory. @ [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#update_a_video). It is updating only tags.